# Why do most web hosting services support only PHP as the server-side language?

Tags: java, python, open-source, server-side

I have been working with Java and Python, so I found a nice web host which has support for these.

But my question is, why is it so hard to find such hosts?

I understand that PHP is easy, and I also understand that Oracle host is hard to find ($$$ of course), but what do they have against some good open-source, completely free Java [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework), [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages), [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29), Python, [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails), Perl, etc.?

It is so rare to find hosts ... not to mention freelancer bids.

Comment: Google's AppEngine supports Java. Also, http://tinyurl.com/2bt3euv makes it seem like there's plenty of easy to find java hosting companies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Java, hosting is more complicated. You can't just load mod_java and go, you need [Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) or [JBoss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBoss), or some other Servlet/JSP hosting environment, and they're non-trivial to configure and maintain.

With Python, I think it's just that it's not as commonly used for web services. I use much more Python than PHP, but I don't tend to use it for web stuff, aside from the occasional Django site. (Mind you, the company I host my personal stuff with charges for Java, but offers Python for "free", the same as PHP).

Comment: Why is python free and java not ?

Comment: @HJ-INCPP: It's the same as php. With python, it's a simple apache module (mod_python), which can be enabled, no problem. Python scripts just need the right suffix, and be in the right directory, they get picked up by Apache, handled, and you're done. This in no way resembles the process you have to go through to get JSPs and Servlets to function. You need a servlet container (Tomcat/Jboss), and you need to write xml configuration files, etc for each app. So the host has to make a lot more available to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more likely to have PHP because the PHP module and Apache come together on Linux more often. However, I still hosted Python web applications by installing Python on my hosted service and working around all the environment related issues. It's not ideal, but that was the only way to do it.

You can check out some of these if they work for you:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/FreeHosts

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because of the popularity of PHP, compared to other tools?

https://stackoverflow.com/tags

In addition, Java is *mostly* used for enterprise applications.

Comment: That's a terrible metric. This site is php heavy as compared to the actual development going on in the world: http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html

Comment: I don't see any difference in this case, PHP doubles Python. Also, in that list, you don't have specific data on tools like ASP or JSP. But thanks for the info.

Comment: And Java doubles php, but Java hosting isn't nearly as common as php hosting. Php is more web-centric than either Python or Java, so web hosting is more common.

Answer (score 0):

Java and Ruby on Rails are expensive in resources (CPU and RAM).

Perl is supported pretty much everywhere...but not published. Probably not so requested
Python...I don't know. Probably not so requested. But there are several free Python hosting options, like http://code.google.com/appengine/, and many others (of course, PHP is still the king by far).

Answer (score -2):

I haven't seen Python support missing from any webhosts ... I'm not sure where you're looking.  Checkout out [Webfaction](http://www.webfaction.com/) - they really are the best for smaller stuff bar none.